# Where's the scam in this bank fraud call?

Tags: united-states, scams, fraud, call-options

Callee C, in the United States, receives a text message nominally from Bank B's fraud center, from a short SMS code, noting first that it's a "FreeMSG" asking about a particular purchase; "If valid reply YES, fraud NO. To Opt Out, STOP."

Bank B is a national bank in the United States.

Callee C, who has no relationship with Bank B and who has not given that phone number to any bank, figures this is just a phishing attempt or similar, and ignores it.

15 minutes later, Callee C receives a voicemail following [this script](https://www.jaxfcu.org/debit-card-fraud-message-real-fake/) almost exactly.  However, the bank name in the voicemail matches the one from the text message, and is not Jax or any other credit union.  The cardholder name given in the voicemail (which I'll call Asked-For A) is not recognized by C.

Searching on Bank B's website for the phone number (matching the one in the script) produces no results. However, Callee C recognizes from recent experience that legitimate fraud prevention calls from banks often request customers call back on numbers not published by the bank, and calling the bank's published fraud prevention number can require over an hour of frustrating time and 3-4 supervisors to get transferred to someone who recognizes and confirms that the message was in fact legitimate.

The call appears in the phone's call logs, but the callee recalls no ringing even though they were sitting in front of the phone which was not silenced at the time.

Callee C regularly receives spam/scam phone calls, and generally ignores them, but this one seems like it might be either misdirected or a new kind of scam.

If C were [at least collaborating with] a scammer to defraud A, that would seem relatively straightforward: C would answer YES and/or call back to confirm the transaction.

Assume that C is not a scammer or collaborator with the scammer. Further assume that C applies the Golden Rule and has some empathy for A, but doesn't know if A is a real person or a fictitious one invented for the purpose of a more elaborate scam targeting C.

If it is a scam, how does it work?  If it's not, what should C do?
How can someone in C's position figure out if a call like this is a scam or not?

Answer (score 6):

Simplest answer is simply that this isn't fraud, but is a wrong number (maybe the person named, A, actually has a number 1 or 2 digits off yours).  But, it certainly could be a scam of various types (and there's certainly no reason to call the number back in any event). If you keep getting calls/texts about this person's account, consider calling the main line of the bank - it's possible they can help you out.

Here're some possible scams:

- Dialing scams, like the first one listed [here](https://www.pathwayscu.com/phone-scams/), where the idea is to get you to call their (toll) number and generate revenue that way.
- Identifying individuals who are likely to be vulnerable to fraud - think of it as throwing a bunch of lures out and seeing who bites.  People who call back to a number they don't recognize are more likely to be willing victims of fraud.
- The typical bank information fraud - they answer, say that they must've gotten something wrong, ask you typical bank information verification questions, and you've just given them your information.  Of course, you don't have a relationship with them, but they're casting a wide net - some of the answerers will have such a relationship.

Comment: Also, you should always use the published bank fraud department number and sit through the transfers. Spoofing fraud alert calls is easy. If there's a need to follow-up, then ask for an unpublished, direct number while you're on the call.